# MongoDB - Sharding migrateThread randomly running for more than 12 hours

Tags: mongodb

12 hours ago I received a notification from my LibreNMS monitoring tool that the mongo daemon on one of my 12 MongoDB (version 3.2.11) servers was having trouble (took more than 10 seconds to connect). I decided to ignore it and wait it out, I just assumed it was a bit busy.

A couple hours later I was getting a little bit worried when I ran `db.currentOp()`. I saw that there was a operation running `migrateThread` with the message "step 2 of 5" along with a couple inserts with the message "query not recording (too large)".

After doing some internet search I saw it can take some as it is migrating data chunks to the other servers. So I decided to wait it out as I don't want to interrupt it and end up having 2 TB of data being corrupted on a production instance.

Now 12 hours has passed and I am starting to worry about what's going on. It is still at "step 2 of 5", the processor load is very high, but it still seems to be moving chunks around and spawning new migrateThread operations along with lots of "query not recording (too large)" inserts.

Here's a part of my `currentOp()` log:

```
        {
        "desc" : "migrateThread",
        "threadId" : "139962853246720",
        "active" : true,
        "opid" : -2003494368,
        "secs_running" : 408,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(408914923),
        "op" : "none",
        "ns" : "data.logs",
        "query" : {

        },
        "msg" : "step 2 of 5",
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "w",
            "Database" : "w",
            "Collection" : "w"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(37984),
                    "w" : NumberLong(37982)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1),
                    "w" : NumberLong(37981),
                    "W" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "W" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "W" : NumberLong(1446)
                }
            },
            "Collection" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1),
                    "w" : NumberLong(37980),
                    "W" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "acquireWaitCount" : {
                    "W" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "W" : NumberLong(3224)
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "desc" : "conn451221",
        "threadId" : "139962959451904",
        "connectionId" : 451221,
        "client" : "10.0.0.111:57408",
        "active" : true,
        "opid" : -2003439364,
        "secs_running" : 0,
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong(37333),
        "op" : "insert",
        "ns" : "data.logs",
        "query" : {
            "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
        },
        "numYields" : 0,
        "locks" : {
            "Global" : "w",
            "Database" : "w",
            "Collection" : "w"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Global" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(1),
                    "w" : NumberLong(1)
                }
            },
            "Database" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "w" : NumberLong(1)
                }
            },
            "Collection" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "w" : NumberLong(1)
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

When I check `mongod.log` I see the following:

```
2017-05-04T19:08:14.203Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] starting receiving-end of migration of chunk { _id: -8858253000066304220 } -> { _id: -8857450400323294366 } for collection data.logs from mongo03:27017 at epoch 56f5410efed7ec477fb62e31
2017-05-04T19:08:14.350Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] Deleter starting delete for: data.logs from { _id: -8858253000066304220 } -> { _id: -8857450400323294366 }, with opId: 2291391315
2017-05-04T19:08:14.350Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] rangeDeleter deleted 0 documents for data.logs from { _id: -8858253000066304220 } -> { _id: -8857450400323294366 }
2017-05-04T19:18:26.625Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] Waiting for replication to catch up before entering critical section
2017-05-04T19:18:26.625Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] migrate commit succeeded flushing to secondaries for 'data.logs' { _id: -8858253000066304220 } -> { _id: -8857450400323294366 }
2017-05-04T19:18:36.499Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] migrate commit succeeded flushing to secondaries for 'data.logs' { _id: -8858253000066304220 } -> { _id: -8857450400323294366 }
2017-05-04T19:18:36.788Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] about to log metadata event into changelog: { _id: "mongo01-2017-05-04T21:18:36.788+0200-590b7e8c1bc38fe0dd61db45", server: "mongo01", clientAddr: "", time: new Date(1493925516788), what: "moveChunk.to", ns: "data.logs", details: { min: { _id: -8858253000066304220 }, max: { _id: -8857450400323294366 }, step 1 of 5: 146, step 2 of 5: 279, step 3 of 5: 611994, step 4 of 5: 0, step 5 of 5: 10162, note: "success" } }
2017-05-04T19:19:04.059Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] starting receiving-end of migration of chunk { _id: -9090190725188397877 } -> { _id: -9088854275798899737 } for collection data.logs from mongo04:27017 at epoch 56f5410efed7ec477fb62e31
2017-05-04T19:19:04.063Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] Deleter starting delete for: data.logs from { _id: -9090190725188397877 } -> { _id: -9088854275798899737 }, with opId: 2291472928
2017-05-04T19:19:04.064Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] rangeDeleter deleted 0 documents for data.logs from { _id: -9090190725188397877 } -> { _id: -9088854275798899737 }
2017-05-04T19:28:16.709Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] Waiting for replication to catch up before entering critical section
2017-05-04T19:28:16.709Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] migrate commit succeeded flushing to secondaries for 'data.logs' { _id: -9090190725188397877 } -> { _id: -9088854275798899737 }
2017-05-04T19:28:17.778Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] migrate commit succeeded flushing to secondaries for 'data.logs' { _id: -9090190725188397877 } -> { _id: -9088854275798899737 }
2017-05-04T19:28:17.778Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] about to log metadata event into changelog: { _id: "mongo01-2017-05-04T21:28:17.778+0200-590b80d11bc38fe0dd61db46", server: "mongo01", clientAddr: "", time: new Date(1493926097778), what: "moveChunk.to", ns: "data.logs", details: { min: { _id: -9090190725188397877 }, max: { _id: -9088854275798899737 }, step 1 of 5: 3, step 2 of 5: 4, step 3 of 5: 552641, step 4 of 5: 0, step 5 of 5: 1068, note: "success" } }
2017-05-04T19:28:34.889Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] starting receiving-end of migration of chunk { _id: -8696921045434215002 } -> { _id: -8696381531400161154 } for collection data.logs from mongo06:27017 at epoch 56f5410efed7ec477fb62e31
2017-05-04T19:28:35.134Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] Deleter starting delete for: data.logs from { _id: -8696921045434215002 } -> { _id: -8696381531400161154 }, with opId: 2291544986
2017-05-04T19:28:35.134Z I SHARDING [migrateThread] rangeDeleter deleted 0 documents for data.logs from { _id: -8696921045434215002 } -> { _id: -8696381531400161154 }
```

So it is taking a very long time to migrate the data. Is it something I should worry about? Should I take any action or just leave it and wait it out?

Just to be clear, I didn't start any migration myself. It happened all by itself. So that's why I am a little confused.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved itself, just had to wait for a long time. The other servers started with the "RangeDeleter" operations afterwards and now it seems to be all good.